# Extract all polygons states of a country

Tags: overpass-api

I need polygons of states in my Country.

After many tries, I got to this. It does return the states of my country, but there are no paths and many items that I did not want.

I've been using http://overpass-turbo.eu/ to test my queries.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Czechia}}->.searchArea;
(
  relation["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="7"](area.searchArea);
);

// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I want to know:

- What I need to do to get polygons of results (the states in my case)
- Why am I getting roads and other stuff when I am specifying boundary and admin_level.
- How to do a similar query next time (I will be getting at least the same for Slovakia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the polygons, you can convert the json result of your query to GeoJSON.

You can test it in http://overpass-turbo.eu/ by running the query and then clicking the *Export* button and choosing the *GeoJSON* format.

The output will contain the states and administrative centers as items of the `features` array. Each item will contains its polygon coordinates in `geometry.coordinates`.
I don't know how to filter out the administrative centers via a query, but you can easily filter out those items on the client side when processing the GeoJSON. I did not see any other unwanted data other than that.

Sample output (abbreviated for readability):

```
{
    ...
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "@id": "relation/435509",
          "ISO3166-2": "CZ-806",
          "admin_level": "7",
          "boundary": "administrative",
          "name": "okres Ostrava-město",
          ...
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                18.3400673,
                49.7592689
              ],
              [
                18.3403166,
                49.7590688
              ],
              [
                18.3406238,
                49.7586477
              ],
              ...
```

Regarding similar queries - it depends on the data available and is country specific.
E.g. for Slovakia, the lowest `admin_level` which returns areas covering the whole state is `4` and that setting returns only the regions (which is a partitioning of a higher level than the one that you are using for the Czech republic).

Comment: The output sample is exactly what I was looking for! But nor the answer nor in the link is any code or explanation on how to get the result you showed.

Comment: The answer contains instructions how to get that output manually - by using the export functionality available on the overpass-turbo.eu page. And if you want to do it programatically, please specify which language you are using. There are different libraries which do the JSON to GeoJSON conversion.

Comment: I did not know my query was giving me the correct result...  Thanks. The data is HUGE! Gonna have to simplify it some. But thanks... This did the job